# Regex for Singapore vehicle number

Tags: javascript

I need a regular expression in Javascript for singapore vehicle NUMBER.

Expression should match following patterns.
eg : AMN0178S

vehicle registration number accepted format is : 3alphabets - 4numeric - 1alphabet.

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: yes (^[A-Za-z]{3,}$)([0-9]{4})([A-Za-z]{1,})

Comment: Why the commas? If you want exactly 3 letters, thats `{3}`, not `{3,}`; `{3,}` is "3 or more". Also, `$` means "and the string should end right there", so there is no point to place it in the middle of your regex. Maybe a look at this guide would be worth it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Noted.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex `[A-Za-z]{3}[\d]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}`.

```js
console.log(/^[A-Za-z]{3}[\d]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/.test('AmN0178S'));
console.log(/^[A-Za-z]{3}[\d]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/.test('Am10178S'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `[A-Za-z]{1}` be the same that just `[A-Za-z]`, and `[\d]` the same that `\d`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest solution. \d means digits, [a-zA-Z] means any alphabet character. {3} and {4} means 3 and 4 of that type. ^ means beginning, $ means end.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}[a-zA-Z]$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-z]{3}\d{4}[A-z]{1}
```

Meaning: 3 characers A-z followed by 4 single digits followed by 1 character A-z.

You can change it to A-Z for only capitals